# OpenLayers: no new attempts to load tile if custom tileLoadFunction fails

Tags: load, openlayers, tile

I‘m using a custom tileLoadFunction in order to retrieve my tiles via an XMLHttpRequest (the reason for this is that the builtin loader doesn‘t always send the session cookie along to the server).

The loader works, however, if (e.g due to a network problem) the request for a tile fails, OpenLayers will not call the loader again for this tile.

My question now, is there a way to let OpenLayers know that the tile was not loaded successfully?

Thanks, Simon

```
function getTile(tile, url) 
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.open('GET', url);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 0)
        {
            tile.getImage().src = "";
            //console.log("error " + url)
        }
    };      

    xhr.onload = function () {
        var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(this.response);
        var blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView]);
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
        tile.getImage().src = imageUrl;
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you

Comment: have you tried to use `tileloaderror` event?

Comment: Thank you, but I‘m not sure how this would make a difference - in the tile load function above I have already the possibility to handle the error. The problem is, what to do in order for the loading of this particular tile to be retried. By now I have adopted a hack, executing tile.load() after a timeout of 1s. Not beautiful, but functional so far.

Answer (score 1):

the cache prevents the tile from being loaded again.
But you can use a trick: just set the tile loader function again by calling `setTileLoadFunction`, [it internally clears the cache](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/2eea8df75af5f548cad4e8e0d0597e487d90a06b/src/ol/source/urltile.js#L144).

```
setTileLoadFunction(getTile)
```

Comment: Thanks dube, but this can serve only as an interim workaround, as it would also cause all the existing tiles to be discarded and reloaded. In addition, in the tileLoadFunction the layer's source is not available for resetting the tileLoadFunction (especially if there are multiple map layers handled by a layer switcher).

Comment: Resetting all data should not concern you if your problem is _doesn‘t always send the session cookie_, which reads as "session not valid". But of course it is a hack and you should investigate Chase Chois suggestion.

Comment: I am authenticating my tiles with JWT and this solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks dube.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but in your error catching you can set the tile state and attach an error-checking function to the tile setState event as Chase Choi noted:

```
if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 0) {
    tile.getImage().src = "";
    tile.setState(3);  //sets state to ERROR 
}
```

```
layer.getSource()on.("tileloaderror", handleTileLoadError); //set a timeout and run getTile again
```

However, I have found that a better approach is to include a retry in your request and place a limit on iterations:

```
const retries = {};
function getTile(tile, URL) { 

    ...

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 0) {
        retries[src] = (retries[src] || 0) + 1);
        if (retries[src] <= 3) {
            setTimeout(() => tile.load(), retries[src] * 1000);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```